# jQuery clone the active img inside a div and make it the div's background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

This is the html that I have so far:

```
<div class="testimonials">
  <div class="item active">
    <div class="testimonial-bg"></div>
    <div class="testimonial-img">
        <img src="img/testimonial-img1.jpg" alt="" />
        <p>
            Hanna's Story
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="testimonial-bg"></div>
    <div class="testimonial-img">
        <img src="img/testimonial-img2.jpg" alt="" />
        <p>
            Hanna's Story
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the img tag inside the '.item' which has the class of 'active' to be the background image of .testimonials also. As each slide changes, the item image will change, and thus this background image should also change. How can I do this?

The Slider is bootstrap's default carousel. The code can be seen here: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNjaEQ

Comment: Please provide a working jsFiddle.

Comment: ok, i'll make one real quick

Comment: which slider you are using ??

Comment: I am using bootstrap's default carousel

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNjaEQ      Here is the Fiddle

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".item.active").each(function() {

  var $myBg  = $(".testimonial-bg", this),
      $myImg = $(".testimonial-img img", this);

  $myBg.css({backgroundImage: "url('"+ $myImg[0].src +"')"});

});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. Can you make a fiddle? Or use the one I've made http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNjaEQ